# How to convert a char into an unsigned int?

Tags: c, struct, floating-point, int, unions

How the program works

```
./my program 1 10000100 01000000001000001000000
// Reads the argv's
// Converts them into unsigned ints
```

How do I convert the char* into an unsigned int? I assume I use bit manipulation, but I am a little lost on the conversion of a char to an unsigned int.

The code.

```
struct _float {
    unsigned int sign:1, exp:8, frac:23;
};

union _bits32 {
    float    fval;  // Bits as a float
    Word     xval;  // Bits as a word
    Float32 bits;  // manipulate individual bits
};

union _bits32 getBits(char *sign, char *exp, char *frac);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    u = getBits(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
    return 0;
}

// Here I am converting the char's into unsigned ints
union _bits32 getBits(char *sign, char *exp, char *frac) {
    Union32 new;

    // convert char *sign into a single bit in new.bits
    new.bits.sign = *sign;

    // convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits
    new.bits.exp = *exp;

    // convert char *frac into a 23-bit value in new.bits
    new.bits.frac = *frac;

    return new;
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to store a char into my _float" ??? "How can I store a char * in a struct which as an unsigned int" ???

Comment: @Stargateur But how can I store an int like this 00010000? Wouldn't c just read that as 0?

Comment: Edited my question, its a little easier to read

Comment: Textbook wrong way to use bitfields and unions.  You are into "implementation defined" territory.  This will fail at some point.

Comment: @old_timer What do you mean?

Comment: multiple items in a union share the same memory space, but there is no reason to assume alignment.  bitfields have the same alignment problem, no guarantee on alignment within the space the occupy.  there is no reason to assume the bitfield you call sign will end up lining up with the sign bit for example, per the language.

Comment: @old_timer For example, the `char *sign` is only 1 character long. Either 1 or 0. Wouldn't I only need to manipulate 1 bit? which is either 0 or 1 in the unsigned int?

Comment: you can try unsigned int *x; float f;  x=&f;  then do masking and shifting with *x.

Comment: Usually that gives a warning or something. I would agree that the use of structs/unions is odd, it really isn't relevant to the question. The user is asking about parsing the individual arguments into ints.

Comment: You have to convert from ascii to binary if you want to move the value over from a command line.  the sign bit would be the only one that works.

Comment: @James why bother helping if the code is broken in general.  True the question is about ASCII to binary and not about structs and unions.  Assuming the structs and unions happen to line up just right on this computer with this compiler on this day, then getting the command line into those bits has to do with understanding ASCII and binary.

Comment: The standard for 32-bit floating point numbers is generally fixed (IEEE 754)  it is unlikely that it will change. This may also be an exercise in understanding that representation, in which it is helpful to the learner to work with it manually, but verify the results by having other code interpret the bits. This looks more like a learning exercise than a long-lasting piece of code that needs to not break.

Comment: Understood, I wasnt talking about the floating point format, but that is a good point about assumptions of the format.  This also appears to be a bit manipulation question, masking and shifting from day one are better than bitfields.  Not just pulling the bits out of the ASCII string (do we need to talk about the assumption that this is ASCII?)  but isolating the sign, exponent and mantissa.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to read each bit (1 character per bit) and save that to an integer in the correct bit positions. Here is a function that would do so for an arbitrary length up to 32 bits.

```
// Takes in the string with the bits (e.g. "01010100011")
// Returns the integer represented by those bits (leading bits are 0's)
int parseFromBinary(char* bitString) {
  int val = 0;
  int i = 0;
  // While there are more characters
  while (bitString[i] != 0) {
    // Shift everything left (multiply by 2) to make room for the new bit
    val <<= 1;
    // Add the new bit (no effect if it is a 0)
    val |= bitString[i] - '0';
    i++;
  }
  return val;
}
```

You would want to call this function once for each field, though it really isn't necessary to loop over the 1 sign bit, and that would arguably make things less clear.

Comment: could you explain why we shift everything to the left?

Comment: If I have the string "1", I expect to get 0b000001 out.
If I add another character (seen on the second iteration of the loop) to get "10", I expect to get 0b00000010. Since there are 2 bits, the leftmost one represents decimal 2 (second bit), if there were 3 bits, the leftmost bit represents decimal 4 (third bit). We shift left each time because we just learned that there is another digit that is now the lowest spot.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question, is there a way for me to actually `printf` the `sign`, `exp` and `frac`? I would like to try play around with this to maybe have a better understanding

Comment: printf("0x%X\n",new.bits.frac);

Comment: @old_timer That doesn't seem to print anything at all (no errors either)

Comment: An ASCII '0' is 0x30 a '1' is 0x31, so your sign string is 0x31,0x30,0x30,0x30... and you want that to be binary 0b1000...   so as shown here you need to extract the lsbit from each character assuming that the command line contains valid data.

Comment: it is printing 0x30 right?  because as shown in your question *frac = 0x30.

Comment: What format are you looking for? do you mean before or after conversion?
If you want decimal: printf("%d\n", new.bits.frac)

Comment: Edit: Nvm, sorry, I forgot to comment the code out which was calling the function

Comment: then you have other problems.

Comment: @James @old_timer the code seems to get stuck (I think its stuck in the while loop). Is it because there is no `i++;` at the end?

Comment: Why not just using a library function for that purpose? Normally `strtoull(bitString, 0, 2)` should do the trick of the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int ra,rb;

    if(argc<2) return(1);

    rb=0;
    for(ra=0;argv[1][ra];ra++)
    {
        rb<<=1;
        rb|=argv[1][ra]&1;
    }
    printf("0x%08X\n",rb);
    return(0);
}
```

build and run

```
gcc so.c -o so
./so 000100000
0x00000020
./so 101010101
0x00000155
./so 010101010
0x000000AA
./so 101
0x00000005
```

the string "101" looks like this when run:

```
argv[1]={0x31,0x30,0x31};
```

because it is ASCII. (google ASCII chart and go to images)

The desired result is the value 0b101 which is 0x5 or decimal 5.

Generally you want to parse through that string

```
argv[1][0]=0x31;
argv[1][1]=0x30;
argv[1][2]=0x31;
argv[1][3]=0x00;
```

starting with the first byte in the string 0x31 need to extract the lsbit and save it.  This is the 0b1xx bit of our final number which we can see as humans but need to get the program to do it.  When on to the next byte if you shift your accumulator left one and make room for the next bit you will end up with 0b10 and orr in a zero ending up with 0b10 which is these two bits of our final answer 0b10x
now shift the 0b10 left one to make room for the next bit, take that bit from the ascii byte resulting in 0b101.  You can repeat this as long as you have room in the variable.

Because the string order left to right is array item 0,1,2,3.  And these line up with the msbit to lsbit in that order of the binary value we want to extract the first byte in the array is our msbit, so if we keep shifting that left as we add in more bits our msbit ends up on the left as desired and the last bit we add, the last byte in the string, and that will be the lsbit when done.

EDIT

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int ra,rb;

    if(argc<2) return(1);

    rb=0;
    for(ra=0;argv[1][ra];ra++)
    {
        rb<<=1;
        rb|=argv[1][ra]&1;
    }
    //printf("0x%08X\n",rb);
    printf("0b");
    for(ra=0x80000000;ra;ra>>=1)
    {
        if(ra&rb) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

gives

```
./so 101
0b00000000000000000000000000000101
./so 101010101
0b00000000000000000000000101010101
./so 111000111000
0b00000000000000000000111000111000
```

EDIT2

You really have to understand binary, ASCII, visual representations, bit manipulation, etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int ra,rb;

    if(argc<2) return(1);

    rb=0;
    for(ra=0;argv[1][ra];ra++)
    {
        rb<<=1;
        rb|=argv[1][ra]&1;
    }
    printf("hex %08X\n",rb);
    printf("octal %011o\n",rb);
    printf("binary ");
    for(ra=0x80000000;ra;ra>>=1)
    {
        if(ra&rb) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return(0);
}
```

gives

```
./so 101010101
hex 00000155
octal 00000000525
binary 00000000000000000000000101010101
./so 111000111
hex 000001C7
octal 00000000707
binary 00000000000000000000000111000111
./so 101
hex 00000005
octal 00000000005
binary 00000000000000000000000000000101
```

these binary bits

```
000111000111
```

to make them easier to read and communicate can be broken into octal:

```
000 111 000 111
```

start from the right and take three at a time, this gives 0707

Or hex, start from the right take them four at a time

```
0001 1100 0111
```

this gives 1C7

But in order to "see" them the computer went back to ASCII (and this day and age that was converted into a bigger representation that includes language differences)

I manually turned the binary number 0101 into 0x31,0x30,0x31 so we could see "101".  The formatted printf, 0101 became 0x35 so we could see "5", likewise the binary number 0101, became 0x30,0x35 so we could see "05".

EDIT3

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int ra,rb;

    if(argc<2) return(1);

    rb=0;
    for(ra=0;argv[1][ra];ra++)
    {
        rb<<=1;
        rb|=argv[1][ra]&1;
    }
    printf("binary (base 2) ");
    for(ra=0x80000000;ra;ra>>=1)
    {
        char rc;
        if(ra&rb) rc=0x31; else rc=0x30;
        printf("%c",rc);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("base four ");
    for(ra=30;;ra-=2)
    {
        char rc;
        rc=(rb>>ra)&3;
        rc+=0x30;
        printf("%c",rc);
        if(ra==0) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("octal (base 8) ");
    for(ra=30;;ra-=3)
    {
        char rc;
        rc=(rb>>ra)&7;
        rc+=0x30;
        printf("%c",rc);
        if(ra==0) break;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("hexadecimal (base 16) ");
    for(ra=28;;ra-=4)
    {
        char rc;
        rc=(rb>>ra)&0xF;
        rc+=0x30;
        if(rc>0x39) rc+=7;
        printf("%c",rc);
        if(ra==0) break;
    }
    printf("\n");

    return(0);
}

./so 101
binary (base 2) 00000000000000000000000000000101
base four 0000000000000011
octal (base 8) 00000000005
hexadecimal (base 16) 00000005
./so 1010
binary (base 2) 00000000000000000000000000001010
base four 0000000000000022
octal (base 8) 00000000012
hexadecimal (base 16) 0000000A
./so 11001100
binary (base 2) 00000000000000000000000011001100
base four 0000000000003030
octal (base 8) 00000000314
hexadecimal (base 16) 000000CC
./so 111000111
binary (base 2) 00000000000000000000000111000111
base four 0000000000013013
octal (base 8) 00000000707
hexadecimal (base 16) 000001C7
./so 111100001111
binary (base 2) 00000000000000000000111100001111
base four 0000000000330033
octal (base 8) 00000007417
hexadecimal (base 16) 00000F0F
```

EDIT

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rb;
    unsigned int rc;
    char s[32];
    rb=0x1234;
    for(ra=0x8000;ra;ra>>=1)
    {
        printf("0x%04X & 0x%04X = 0x%04X ",ra,rb,ra&rb);
        if(ra&rb) printf("1"); else printf("0");
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(ra=0x8000;ra;ra>>=1)
    {
        if(ra&rb) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(ra=0;ra<16;ra++)
    {
        if((ra&3)==0) printf(" ");
        if((rb>>(15-ra))&1) printf("1"); else printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(rc=0,ra=0x8000;ra;ra>>=1,rc++)
    {
        if(ra&rb) s[rc]='1'; else s[rc]='0';
    }
    s[rc++]='\r';
    s[rc++]='\n';
    s[rc]=0;
    for(ra=0;s[ra];ra++)
    {
        printf("0x%02X ",s[ra]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%s",s);
    return(0);
}
```

output

```
0x8000 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x4000 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x2000 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x1000 & 0x1234 = 0x1000 1
0x0800 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0400 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0200 & 0x1234 = 0x0200 1
0x0100 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0080 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0040 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0020 & 0x1234 = 0x0020 1
0x0010 & 0x1234 = 0x0010 1
0x0008 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0004 & 0x1234 = 0x0004 1
0x0002 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0x0001 & 0x1234 = 0x0000 0
0001001000110100
 0001 0010 0011 0100
0x30 0x30 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x31 0x31 0x30 0x31 0x30 0x30 0x0D 0x0A 
0001001000110100
```

Comment: And naturally you want to also check each item in the string to confirm it is a 0x30 or 0x31 error out if not.  And probably also want to length check to make sure there arent two sign bits specified for example.

Comment: so when we do this, it is stored as hexadecimal in the unsigned int? For example if we have `int x = 1`. we know 1 is stored in `x`. What is stored in the unsigned int?

Comment: hexadecimal is just a visual representation, no, it is binary ones and zeros.

Comment: is there a way to print the binary version of the unsigned int?

Comment: just added that.

Comment: the hex printout is a binary representation as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'm understanding this (sort of). What is `0x80000000`. Like what character is it? It has to represent something?

Comment: 0x80000000 is just bits, nothing to do with characters.  If I assume that unsigned int is 32 bits (I could have properly used uint32_t) then 0x80000000 is the msbit so I can sweep from top to bottom the bits in that variable.  we write from left to right we want to see the bits from left to right so I want to start with bit 31 then 30 then 29... down to bit 0.

Comment: Doesnt sound like you are getting it yet.  Need to think about the bits, the ones and zeros and how they are being tossed about.  Look at the ASCII chart you googled for a while, the good ones have the ASCII character and a decimal and hexadecimal value next to it.  Then think about the logical functions AND, OR, NOT (can generate the others from those three).  And then think about shifting bits left or right...

Comment: This didnt come naturally to me any more than I assume other folks.  My first job had a lot of bit manipulation, so it very quickly was beat into my brain, it just takes some time to separate yourself from base 10 and allow others.  We already use base 60 for time and base 10 for everything else so it is possible to deal with other bases.  Octal and Hexadecimal are natural complements to binary as they are powers of two bases, so when you see 5 in octal you simply think 0b101, and in hex 0b0101.  And vice versa see 0b101 you think 5 in octal hex and for this number decimal as well.

Comment: And once you start to see things as chunks of bits or bytes you might start to understand why bitfields and this type of use of unions can be implemented different ways by different compilers and how to use simple shifts and masks to extract bits which is what the compiler is going to do with that code, you can just make it reliable code by doing the shifts and masks directly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, the "confused" part most likely stems from the fact that `getBits` will store the value in `new.bits` with the bits *reversed*. Similar to *host-to-network* and *network-to-host* byte order, but completely bitwise reversed in your case.

Where you have

```
struct _float {
    unsigned int sign:1, exp:8, frac:23;
};
```

You have a single bitfield where you designate `sign` as the *most-significant* bit. In memory, on a little-endian architecture this will be **bit-0**, not **bit-31**, resulting in your manipulation in `getBits` of `new.bits` leaving `new.fval` and `new.xval` being held in memory backwards.

Now, of course, the simple fix is to reverse your bitfield, e.g.

```
struct _float {
    unsigned int frac:23, exp:8, sign:1;
};
```

To illustrate the point, let's just take `new` and reverse the bits before return. Nothing fancy, just a loop to reverse the bits of an unsigned value, e.g.

```
/* reverse the bits in v, sz number of bits */
unsigned revbits (unsigned v, int sz)
{
    unsigned r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) 
        r |= ((v >> i) & 0x1) << (sz - i - 1);

    return r;
}
```

Also, note in `getBits` you cannot assign the strings to the bitfield values, you must OR and shift each individual bit into the proper location within the bitfield, while subtracting `'0'` to convert from ASCII to integer value, for instance:

```
/* convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits */
for (int i = 0; i < EXP; i++)
    new.bits.exp |= (exp[i] - '0') << i;
```

Now lets reverse the bits of `new` in `getBits` before `return`, e.g.

```
/* convert three bit-strings (already checked)
 * into the components of a struct _float
 */
Union32 getBits (char *sign, char *exp, char *frac) {

    Union32 new = { .xval = 0 };

    /* convert char *sign into a single bit in new.bits */
    new.bits.sign = *sign - '0';

    /* convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < EXP; i++)
        new.bits.exp |= (exp[i] - '0') << i;

    /* convert char *frac into a 23-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAC; i++)
        new.bits.frac |= (frac[i] - '0') << i;

    /* reverse the bit order */
    new.xval = revbits (new.xval, sizeof new.xval * CHAR_BIT);

    return new;
}
```

Now your example correctly outputs `-40.015869`. If you put all the pieces together, and use *constants* in your code, instead of sprinkling *magic numbers* throughout, and using `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h` to insure we have the correct number of bit for our type, and adding a missing `typedef` for `Word` to `unsigned`, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* constants for use in code (don't use magic numbers) */
enum { SIGN = 1, EXP = 8, FRAC = 23 };

typedef struct _float {
    unsigned sign:SIGN, 
             exp :EXP, 
             frac:FRAC;
} Float32;

typedef unsigned Word;  /* you need typedef for unsigned as Word */

union _bits32 {
    float    fval;      /* Bits as a float */
    Word     xval;      /* Bits as a word  */
    Float32  bits;      /* manipulate individual bits (reverse order) */
};
typedef union _bits32 Union32;

/* reverse the bits in v, sz number of bits */
unsigned revbits (unsigned v, int sz)
{
    unsigned r = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) 
        r |= ((v >> i) & 0x1) << (sz - i - 1);

    return r;
}

/* convert three bit-strings (already checked)
 * into the components of a struct _float
 */
Union32 getBits (char *sign, char *exp, char *frac) {

    Union32 new = { .xval = 0 };

    /* convert char *sign into a single bit in new.bits */
    new.bits.sign = *sign - '0';

    /* convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < EXP; i++)
        new.bits.exp |= (exp[i] - '0') << i;

    /* convert char *frac into a 23-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAC; i++)
        new.bits.frac |= (frac[i] - '0') << i;

    /* reverse the bit order */
    new.xval = revbits (new.xval, sizeof new.xval * CHAR_BIT);

    return new;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    union   _bits32 u = { .xval = 0 };

    /* set u (default value is PI to 3.14159) */
    u = getBits (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "0", 
                 argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "10000000", 
                 argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "10010010000111111010000");

    /* output fval */
    printf ("u.fval %f\n", u.fval);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Default case with PI:

```
$ ./bin/floatbits
u.fval 3.141590
```

Using your input:

```
$ ./bin/floatbits 1 10000100 01000000001000001000000
u.fval -40.015869
```

**Rearranging the Order of `Float32`**

As mentioned above, rather than reversing the bits before return in `getBits`, the more straight forward approach is to change the order of `Float32` so that you have the bitfield order as `FRAC, EXP, SIGN` which would make the order in-memory of `bits` consistent with `fval` and `xval`.

Now you can simply fill each in `getBit` (while taking care to fill the bits in proper bit order for your host, e.g. little-endian, least significant bit is highest bit in range, etc.). This simply requires you recognizing that `string[0]` will map to `bit[most-significant]` for each of `FRAC` and `EXP`. With that change, the code would simplify to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* constants for use in code (don't use magic numbers) */
enum { SIGN = 1, EXP = 8, FRAC = 23 };

typedef struct _float {
    unsigned frac:FRAC, 
             exp :EXP, 
             sign:SIGN;
} Float32;

typedef unsigned Word;  /* you need typedef for unsigned as Word */

union _bits32 {
    float    fval;      /* Bits as a float */
    Word     xval;      /* Bits as a word  */
    Float32  bits;      /* manipulate individual bits (reverse order) */
};
typedef union _bits32 Union32;

/* convert three bit-strings (already checked)
 * into the components of a struct _float
 */
Union32 getBits (char *sign, char *exp, char *frac) {

    Union32 new = { .xval = 0 };

    /* convert char *sign into a single bit in new.bits */
    new.bits.sign = *sign - '0';

    /* convert char *exp into an 8-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < EXP; i++)
        new.bits.exp |= (exp[EXP - i - 1] - '0') << i;

    /* convert char *frac into a 23-bit value in new.bits */
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAC; i++)
        new.bits.frac |= (frac[FRAC - i - 1] - '0') << i;

    return new;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    union   _bits32 u = { .xval = 0 };

    /* set u (default value is PI to 3.14159) */
    u = getBits (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "0", 
                 argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "10000000", 
                 argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "10010010000111111010000");

    /* output fval */
    printf ("u.fval %f\n", u.fval);

    return 0;
}
```

(the use/output is the same)

While bitfields are fine to learn, they are rarely portable. If your goal is portable code, then they are best avoided.

Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ++ch) {
        printf("%d\t", ch);
    }

    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ch) {
        printf("%d\t", ch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please explain your code and that how its going to solve the problem, just writing a piece of code is not going to be the solution.